# Space is taking after every String

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matcher

```
String delimiterStr = "|", line="1231|08062016|4441|10|PayeeName1|REF1";
String ISSUE_UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN = "(?<=(^|" + delimiterStr + "))(([^\"" + delimiterStr + "]*)|\"([^\"]*)\")(?=($|" + delimiterStr + "))";

List<String> splitString = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(ISSUE_UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN).matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
  if (matcher.group(3) != null) {//NOPMD,old code
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    splitString.add(matcher.group(3));
  } 
}
System.out.println(splitString.size()+"::--->"+splitString);

OutPut :-  12::--->[1231, , 08062016, , 4441, , 10, , PayeeName1, , REF1, ]
```

Above pattern is taking space after every splitted string as you can see in output. I do not want to take space after every string. It needs to take space if input String has space present in it otherwise it should not take space. What changes needs to be done in my pattern?

Comment: No it isn't. use a for-each loop to print your output. You won't see spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving as expected. When `toString()` is called on a `ArrayList`, it uses `AbstractCollection`'s implementation which goes like :

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' '); // adds space
    }
}
```

You could add a simple loop to verify that spaces are not being added for each element :

```
        for (String s : splitString) {
            System.out.println(s + "X");
        }
```

Comment: String ISSUE_UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN = "([^\"|]*)"; can you explain what values above pattern will take ? Does it take space also.?

Comment: @RBP - It matches anything except quotes and `|`.

Comment: (?<=(^|" + delimiterStr + "))(([^\"" + delimiterStr + "][^" + delimiterStr + "])|\"([^\"])\")(?=($|" + delimiterStr + ")) . If i give line="1231||"; It need to generate 3 length list with 1231 number, and 2 blank space. currently it is generating list of 1 with 1231 number. It is not taking delimiters after that. any idea what changes needed to do to take it as blank

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE_UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN = "(?<=(^|" + delimiterStr + "))(([^\"" + delimiterStr + "]*[^" + delimiterStr + "])|\"([^\"]*)\")(?=($|" + delimiterStr + "))";

Above Pattern resolved my problem.